# generating contour plots for X,Y data in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, contour, temperature

Hi im not sure if this has already been asked before but i couldn't find an answer to satisfy me.

if you had X,Y and Temperature data see below for an example. how would you plot the temperature contour of the data in python

```
X   Y  Temp   
0   0   23
0.1 0   23
0.2 0   23
0.3 0   23
0.4 0   23
0.5 0   23
0.6 0   23
0.7 0   23
0.8 0   23
0.9 0   23
1   0   23
0   0.1 23
0.1 0.1 23
0.2 0.1 23
0.3 0.1 23
0.4 0.1 23
0.5 0.1 23
0.6 0.1 23
0.7 0.1 23
0.8 0.1 23
0.9 0.1 23
1   0.1 23
0   0.2 24
0.1 0.2 24
0.2 0.2 24
0.3 0.2 24
0.4 0.2 24
0.5 0.2 24
0.6 0.2 24
0.7 0.2 24
0.8 0.2 24
0.9 0.2 24
1   0.2 24
0   0.3 23
0.1 0.3 23
0.2 0.3 23
0.3 0.3 23
0.4 0.3 23
0.5 0.3 23
0.6 0.3 23
0.7 0.3 23
0.8 0.3 23
0.9 0.3 23
1   0.3 23
0   0.4 25
0.1 0.4 25
0.2 0.4 25
0.3 0.4 25
0.4 0.4 25
0.5 0.4 25
0.6 0.4 25
0.7 0.4 25
0.8 0.4 25
0.9 0.4 25
1   0.4 25
0   0.5 23
0.1 0.5 23
0.2 0.5 23
0.3 0.5 23
0.4 0.5 23
0.5 0.5 23
0.6 0.5 23
0.7 0.5 23
0.8 0.5 23
0.9 0.5 23
1   0.5 23
```

Comment: There are already plenty of examples demonstrating this: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/contour_demo.html

Comment: The typical plotting library is matplotlib which allows contour plots. Have a look at [this discussion](http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/plotting-a-contour-map-from-CSV-file-td16317.html) about how to do a contour plot from a csv