# Plotting contours from data csv

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have data within a csv file with Temperature, x, y and z points arranged in columns. The z points can be negated as it remains 0 through my data acquisition.

I'd like to simply obtain a contour plot of this data.

My problem is essentially the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19905792/generating-contour-plots-for-x-y-data-in-python) but it got redirected to other threads where I still couldn't figure out what was going on.

Edit: Here's my unfinished code which should open the data? I don't know where to go from here.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.mlab import griddata

import csv

data = np.genfromtxt('tempcontour0.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=[('t',float),('x',float),('y',float),('z',float)],usecols=(0,1,2))

T=data['t']
X=data['x']
Y=data['y']

z = np.zeros((len(X),2))
z[:,0] = X
z[:,1] = Y

plt.contour()
plt.show()
```

The data file is like so:

```
T,x,y,z
316.002,0,0,0
309.314,0.00839113,0,0
309.67,0.0172418,0,0
310.34,0.0265772,0,0
310.903,0.0364239,0,0
311.558,0.0468098,0,0
312.704,0.0577645,0,0
313.582,0.0693192,0,0
314.582,0.0815067,0,0
316.2,0.0943616,0,0
317.391,0.107921,0,0
318.93,0.122222,0,0
322.662,0.137307,0,0
325.549,0.153218,0,0
339.193,0.17,0,0
338.943,0,0.0208333,0
341.134,0.00839113,0.0208333,0
341.692,0.0172418,0.0208333,0
```

Comment: First off, you should break the problem down - first read the data from the csv, then plot.  Quite frankly, the documentation you linked to is very clear ... so why don't you try it?  Then if you have trouble, come back with a *specific* question about what's wrong (and post the code you tried).

Comment: @Ajean, I'm not the same account owner considering that question was asked around 2 years ago it seems unlikely that I wouldn't have figured the problem out by now. 

Specifically. I don't actually understand what is going on in the code, I really need a hand-holding step by step of what's going on, something I can't really seem to find.

From what I can tell it's generating a grid which is equally spaced based upon it's data set and then interpolating the data so that it can be plotted?

Answer (score -1):

First you have to read the file with something like:

```
    from numpy import genfromtxt
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    data = genfromtxt('file.csv', delimiter = ',')
```

Then you need to plot it but you need to know how to reshape the array, for instance it looks like your data goes 15 x values before incrementing in the y so:

```
    x = data[:, 1].reshape(15, yincrement)
    y = data[:, 2] .reshape(15,yincrement)
    z = data[:,0].reshape(15,yincrement)

    plt.contour(x,y,z)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: The point at which I've gotten up to is importing the data which I think is correct. 

`data = np.genfromtxt('tempcontour0.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=[('t',float),('x',float),('y',float),('z',float)], usecols=(0,1,2))`

Then I declare `T=data['t']` `X=data['x']`, `Y=data['y']`. From there I'm getting a bit lost. What's with the z array of zeros?

Comment: I used the z array of zeros because contour is looking for a 2D array so I initialized a 2D array and then put x into 1 row and y into the other row of the 2D array, so contour would be happy, it can be done with the x,y and z as well if you like.

Comment: Right, that makes sense. I got something to plot using this method, but it looks all blocky and not exactly what I envisioned :) I can't edit it to the main post but It's definitely not right!

I've editted the main post with the code I have and a tiny amount of the data file I'm using for it.

Comment: Just got an error about having too many indices?

[This](https://i.imgur.com/97r2x0P.png) was what was produced before.

Comment: Why does your data start at x = 0 but when after it finishes it's first run through (i.e. at 0.17) it jumps down to 0.02 instead of down to 0?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure, that's just how paraView saved it. I'd assume it works itself in layers upwards? It's meant to be a 2D cross sectional slice of a CFD fire problem.

Comment: Maybe if you remove that first data point you may be able to get it to reshape properly. I tried it with some random numbers and it worked fine.